# Language settings in master vs core

Tags: multilingual

Recently we discovered than we have some versioned items in Sitecore tree, in languages not supported by our sites, event not set as language in our Sitecore settings. Today we were removing these versioned items of not supported languages, when we noticed that the languages added in core database are different than languages added in master database.

Which is the purpose of the languages defined in core? In master we have set the supported languages in our web sites, but in core all the languages set are language which we never have supported them. Looking at it, we have several questions.

First of all why Sitecore allow to have different languages set in Core and Master? Which are the purpose of Core language? In master we added only the languages supported in our sitecore websites is it that right?

In the future our current Sitecore websites will support more languages, these new languages have to be added only in Master as we have done until now, or is it recommend to add to in Core too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC the languages in the Core database relate the the language versions that the Sitecore admin pages are displayed in. So this would change the text in the Sitecore interface. This is known as the `Client Language`

The languages in the master DB relate the the `Content Language`

Comment: Thanks. English is the only language that we support in Sitecore admin. By this reason I understand that we can delete the other language with out worries, isn't it?